# Learning to iterate from the Tweepy doc. How do I solve this 'Unresolved Reference'?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm new to coding and I'm struggling with code from the Tweepy doc. `process_page` is showing as an `Unresolved Reference` error in my Pycharm IDE. How do I correct this? Thanks

```py
 # Only iterate through the first 200 statuses
for status in tweepy.Cursor(API.user_timeline).items(200):
    process_status(status)

# Only iterate through the first 3 pages
for page in tweepy.Cursor(API.user_timeline).pages(3):
    process_page(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as process_page - it's a template from tweety documentation. They show you how you can use loops, and the function inside it you should replace with own code (whatever you want to do with this data)

Comment: Ok. You got me in the right direction. I'm very thankful. I ran a print function. It worked and a lot of disorganized info was retrieved. Can you suggest a function that would deliver results that a beginner, such as my self, can wrap his mind around?